# MVC Partial View in other view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have two views for creating an Owner or Service Company, each one having their own table.

When a user registers using the standard View->Account->Register view I have added a radio button to ask if they are an Owner or Service Company. What I am trying to achieve is based on which one they select a partial view of the create view for the option they select to appear with a single submit button that both registers the user and creates the Owner or Service Company record.

Look at various tutorials I can only find MVC 4 guides to creating partial views where the Add View dialog looks different. I have read the partial views section in Professional ASP.NET MVC 5 and it suggests you just call a view with a retuns PartialView() method, but I am not sure how to do this outside of a controller and based on a user action (i.e. selecting the radio button).

Any advice gratefully received!

Comment: Is it necessary to do this in one view? Could the `Register()` post method just redirect to a new view to complete one or other of the required forms?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/218ca630-ba50-48fe-af6e-6f754b5894aa.aspx

Comment: I have also thought of that, my concern was not registering the user until Owner or Service Company data was also entered. I have just tried @Html.Partial("~/Views/Owners/Create.cshtml") which rendered the Owners Create view but it rendered the Submit button from that page as well so I have Submit and Register at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Spionred. Your will need a view model containing the models for Register, Owner and ServiceCompany, plus a property for the radio buttons. The initial view has a form with the Register model and radio buttons. Then based on the selected radio button, use ajax to add the relevant partial partial view inside the form tags and reparse the validator. Then post back the view model (the Register and either the Owner or ServiceCompany models will be populated.

Comment: @Stephen, that sounds like a good plan and I think I understand what you are suggesting. I am new so learning as I go. If there are any examples of this please let me know. I will post back how I get on.

Comment: @Spionred, I post an answer (give me a hour) with an outline of how to go about this, however what happens if a user who is registering is (say) a service company, but another user from the same company has already registered - you could get multiple entries representing the same service company?

Comment: @Stephen, The email address is part of the AspNetUsers record and must be unique. I suppose there is nothing stopping someone from registering twice with different email addresses but not sure what we could do about that.

Comment: No, I meant a company usually has more than one employee. If more than one user registers from the same company, they will be all be entering details for the company, despite that fact its already been added by the first employee of that company.

Comment: I am planning to have another user type called contractor. These users will be created by the primary Service Company user in separate view.

Comment: Can't be sure, but I suspect the correct approach would be (1) show login page if not authorized which include a link to register (2) the register page includes a dropdown of registered companies to select the users company, and also includes a link to register a new company if its not in the list (3) the register company page includes options for company type. (4) submitting the register company form redirects back to the register user page where the new company can now be selected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73396/discussion-between-spionred-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend posting to the Register method and based on the value of the selected option, redirect to the relevant view to complete the details. The users table could have a (say) `IsRegistrationComplete` field which is marked as `true` only when the 2nd form has been saved.

To do this in one view, you will need a view model with properties for the `Register` model, `Owner` model, `ServiceCompany` model and selected option.

View model

```
public class RegistrationVM
{
  public RegisterVM Register { get; set; }
  public OwnerVM Owner { get; set; }
  public ServiceCompanyVM ServiceCompany { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public string CompanyType { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
  RegistrationVM model = new RegistrationVM();
  model.Register = new RegisterVM();
  return View(model);
}

public ActionResult Register(RegistrationVM model)
{
  // Either Owner or ServiceCompany properties will be populated
}

public PartialViewResult CreateOwner()
{
  var model = new RegistrationVM();
  model.Owner = new OwnerVM();
  return PartialView(model);
}

public PartialViewResult CreateServiceCompany()
{
  var model = new RegistrationVM();
  model.ServiceCompany = new ServiceCompany();
  return PartialView(model);
}
```

Notes: The partial views should not contain a `<form>` element (it will be inserted inside the `<form>` tag of the main view). The model in the partial views needs to be `RegistrationVM` so the controls are correctly prefixed and can be bound on post back (e.g. `<input name="Owner.SomeProperty" ../>` etc)

View

```
@model RegistrationVM
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  <section>
    // render controls for the register model
  <section>
  <section>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.CompanyType, "owner",new { id = "owner" })
    <label for="owner">Owner</label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.CompanyType, "service",new { id = "service" })
    <label for="service">Service Company</label>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CompanyType)
    <button id="next" type="button">Next</button>
  <section>
  <section id="step2"></section>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" /> // style this as hidden
}
```

Then add a script to handle the `Next` button which validates the existing controls, gets the value of the selected service, uses ajax to load the relevant form, re-parses the validator and displays the submit button

```
var form = $('form');
$('#next').click(function() {
  // Validate what been entered so far
  form.validate();
  if (!form.valid()) {
    return; // correct errors before proceeding
  }
  // Get selected type and update DOM
  var type = $('input[name="CompanyType"]:checked').val();
  if (type == "owner") {
    $('#step2').load('@Url.Action("CreateOwner")');
  } else {
    $('#step2').load('@Url.Action("CreateServiceCompany")');
  }
  // Re-parse validator so client side validation can be applied to the new controls
  form.data('validator', null);
  $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
  // Show submit button
  $('#submit').show();
});
```